# Can we tell if a command is being run by a process or not, by looking at the flock lock file alone?

Tags: lock, flock

Is [util-linux's `flock`](https://serverfault.com/a/82863/16981) implemented based on `flock()` in Linux C API?

Can we tell if a command is being run by a process or not, by looking at the lock file alone?
I found that when a command guarded by `flock` finishes running, there seems no change to the lock file. Here is when it is running and after it finishes running:

```
$ ls -l ../sleep.flock.file 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 t t 0 Oct 30 14:01 ../sleep.flock.file
$ ls -l ../sleep.flock.file 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 t t 0 Oct 30 14:01 ../sleep.flock.file
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. It is explicitly stated in [`man 1 flock`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/flock.1.html) that `flock` command uses `flock()` and [`man 2 flock`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/flock.2.html#NOTES) notes section says that `flock()` is implemented by system call since Linux kernel 2.0.

Comment: Thanks. How about the rest of my questions?

Comment: @Tim You should ask a single question per post... See the help and docs for U&L it will tell you so.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ flock -xn /home/vagrant/forever.lck -c /var/tmp/forever.sh
```

The above flock command will open the /home/vagrant/forever.lck file with an **exclusive (-x) file lock** and execute the specified command (-c).
[forever.sh takes 25 days to complete using sleep 25d command]

If we run a second instance flock will identify there is already an exclusive file lock.

```
$ flock -xn /home/vagrant/forever.lck -c /var/tmp/forever.sh 
$ echo $?
1
```

When flock cannot lock a file and it is executed with the -n (non-blocking) flag, the flock command will exit silently with an exit code that indicates an error has occurred.

The useful thing about flock is that the file lock will be kept in place until the original process completes, at that point flock will release the file lock. This is true whether the process completes successfully or unsuccessfully.

The lock is the key thing here, invisible to `ls`.

[Taken from this article](https://bencane.com/2015/09/22/preventing-duplicate-cron-job-executions/)